# Can't handle key events from fullscreen NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

In my OS X app I need to close a fullscreen window with the Esc key. So I set my instance of `NSWindowController` as a first responder for my window (dynamically created from code in controller), overrode the `keyDown` function with my custom implementation to close the window. But unfortunately, when window has set level to `CGShieldingWindowLevel`, `keyDown` and `keyUp` functions are not called (of course before I press Esc I click to the fullscreen window so window should has focus)

I'm creating the window with:

```
    self.window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: screen.frame,
        styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask,
        backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered,
        defer: false,
        screen: screen
    )

    if let w = window {
        w.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel())
        w.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
        w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        w.makeFirstResponder(self)

        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: w.frame, configuration: config)
        w.contentView = webView!
    }
```

and handle keys with:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if (theEvent.keyCode == 53) {
        self.window?.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docs for `NSWindow.canBecomeKeyWindow`. By default, a borderless window can't become key. You have to override that (and maybe `canBecomeMainWindow`) to return true.